# Update Android studio 3.5 getting proguard warnings

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, proguard

Since I've updated Android studio from 3.4 to 3.5 I'm getting the error on the project. The list of error are below and it seems like missing rules in proguard file.

But once I put these rules:

```
-dontnote androidx.**
-dontwarn androidx.**
```

The project is building infinitely and won't finish. I was waiting 30-40 min with not result at all. (Usually the project build time is 4-5min)

```
Note: there were 6 duplicate class definitions.
      (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#duplicateclass)
Note: the configuration refers to the unknown class 'com.amazonaws.auth.AWS4Signer'
Warning: androidx.appcompat.widget.ActivityChooserView: can't find referenced method 'void saveAttributeDataForStyleable(android.content.Context,int[],android.util.AttributeSet,android.content.res.TypedArray,int,int)' in program class androidx.appcompat.widget.ActivityChooserView
Warning: androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextViewAutoSizeHelper: can't find referenced method 'boolean isHorizontallyScrollable()' in library class android.widget.TextView
Warning: androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextViewAutoSizeHelper: can't find referenced method 'android.text.TextDirectionHeuristic getTextDirectionHeuristic()' in library class android.widget.TextView
Warning: androidx.appcompat.widget.ButtonBarLayout: can't find referenced method 'void saveAttributeDataForStyleable(android.content.Context,int[],android.util.AttributeSet,android.content.res.TypedArray,int,int)' in program class androidx.appcompat.widget.ButtonBarLayout
Warning: androidx.appcompat.widget.DrawableUtils: can't find referenced method 'android.graphics.Insets getOpticalInsets()' in library class android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
Warning: androidx.appcompat.widget.DrawableUtils: can't find referenced class android.graphics.Insets
Warning: androidx.appcompat.widget.DrawableUtils: can't find referenced class android.graphics.Insets
Warning: androidx.appcompat.widget.DrawableUtils: can't find referenced class android.graphics.Insets
Warning: androidx.appcompat.widget.DrawableUtils: can't find referenced class android.graphics.Insets
Warning: androidx.appcompat.widget.DrawableUtils: can't find referenced class android.graphics.Insets
Warning: androidx.appcompat.widget.DrawableUtils: can't find referenced class android.graphics.Insets
Warning: androidx.appcompat.widget.ListPopupWindow: can't find referenced method 'void setEpicenterBounds(android.graphics.Rect)' in library class android.widget.PopupWindow
Warning: androidx.appcompat.widget.ListPopupWindow: can't find referenced method 'void setIsClippedToScreen(boolean)' in library class android.widget.PopupWindow
Warning: androidx.appcompat.widget.MenuPopupWindow: can't find referenced method 'void setTouchModal(boolean)' in library class android.widget.PopupWindow
Warning: androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView: can't find referenced method 'void refreshAutoCompleteResults()' in program class androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView$SearchAutoComplete
Warning: androidx.camera.camera2.impl.compat.CameraManagerCompat$AvailabilityCallbackExecutorWrapper$1: can't find referenced method 'void onCameraAccessPrioritiesChanged()' in library class android.hardware.camera2.CameraManager$AvailabilityCallback
Warning: androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView: can't find referenced method 'void saveAttributeDataForStyleable(android.content.Context,int[],android.util.AttributeSet,android.content.res.TypedArray,int,int)' in program class androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
Warning: androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2: can't find referenced method 'void saveAttributeDataForStyleable(android.content.Context,int[],android.util.AttributeSet,android.content.res.TypedArray,int,int)' in program class androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
```

```
Warning: there were 6 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
         You may need to add missing library jars or update their versions.
         If your code works fine without the missing classes, you can suppress
         the warnings with '-dontwarn' options.
         (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedclass)
Warning: there were 5 unresolved references to program class members.
         Your input classes appear to be inconsistent.
         You may need to recompile the code.
         (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedprogramclassmember)
Warning: there were 7 unresolved references to library class members.
         You probably need to update the library versions.
         Alternatively, you may have to specify the option 
         '-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers'.
         (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedlibraryclassmember)
```

These are proguard rules:

```
# Add project specific ProGuard rules here.
# By default, the flags in this file are appended to flags specified
# in <android sdk path>/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt
# You can edit the include path and order by changing the proguardFiles
# directive in build.gradle.
#
# For more details, see
#   http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/proguard.html

# Add any project specific keep options here:

# If your project uses WebView with JS, uncomment the following
# and specify the fully qualified class name to the JavaScript interface
# class:
#-keepclassmembers class fqcn.of.javascript.interface.for.webview {
#   public *;
#}

# Additional config for retaining stacktrace coherence
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers
-keepattributes LineNumberTable, SourceFile, Exceptions, RuntimeVisibleAnnotations, AnnotationDefault

# Enums
-keepclassmembers enum * { *; }

# This is for retaining proper names of custom Exceptions
-keep public class * extends java.lang.Exception

# Remove log calls
-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
    public static *** d(...);
}
-assumenosideeffects class timber.log.Timber {
    public static *** d(...);
}

# Android
-dontnote android.**
-dontnote com.android.**
## Do not obfuscate but allow shrinking of android-oauth-client
-keepnames class com.wuman.android.auth.** { *; }

# ButterKnife
-keep class butterknife.** { *; }
-dontwarn butterknife.internal.**
-keep class **$$ViewBinder { *; }
-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    @butterknife.* <fields>;
}
-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    @butterknife.* <methods>;
}

# OK
-dontwarn javax.annotation.**
-keepnames class okhttp3.internal.publicsuffix.PublicSuffixDatabase
-dontwarn org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.*
-dontwarn okhttp3.internal.platform.ConscryptPlatform

# Crashlytics
-keep class com.crashlytics.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.crashlytics.**
-dontnote io.fabric.**

# Nucleus (requires default empty constructor, ProGuard removes them)
# https://github.com/konmik/nucleus/issues/126
-keepclassmembers class * extends nucleus5.presenter.Presenter {
    <init>();
}
-dontwarn nucleus.view.NucleusActionBarActivity
-dontnote nucleus5.**

# Google
-keep class com.google.android.gms.common.api.** { *; }
-dontnote com.google.**
# For using GSON @Expose annotation
-keepattributes *Annotation*

# Firebase
-dontnote com.firebase.**

# Amazon AWS Pinpoint
## Class names are needed in reflection
-keepnames class com.amazonaws.**
-keepclassmembers public class com.amazonaws.auth.AWS4Signer {
   public <init>(...);}
## Request handlers defined in request.handlers
-keep class com.amazonaws.services.**.*Handler
## The following are referenced but aren't required to run
-dontwarn com.fasterxml.jackson.**
-dontwarn org.apache.commons.logging.**
## Android 6.0 release removes support for the Apache HTTP client
-dontwarn org.apache.http.**
## The SDK has several references of Apache HTTP client
-dontwarn com.amazonaws.http.**
-dontwarn com.amazonaws.metrics.**
## Spinner indicator
-keep class com.wang.avi.** { *; }
-keep class com.wang.avi.indicators.** { *; }

# Branch.io
-dontwarn com.google.firebase.appindexing.**
-dontwarn com.android.installreferrer.api.**

# Subsampling Scale View
-dontnote com.davemorrissey.**

# RxJava
-dontnote io.reactivex.**

# Realm
-dontnote io.realm.**

# Facebook
-dontnote com.facebook.**

# Dagger
-dontnote dagger.internal.**

# Experimental
-dontwarn **Lambda**

# org.apache.http.legacy (see https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37070898)
-dontnote android.net.http.*
-dontnote org.apache.commons.codec.**
-dontnote org.apache.http.**

# MapWize
-dontwarn com.mapbox.**
-dontwarn com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer
-keep class com.navisens.** {*;}
-keep class org.json.** {*;}

# ChatKit
-keep class * extends com.stfalcon.chatkit.messages.MessageHolders$OutcomingTextMessageViewHolder {
     public <init>(android.view.View, java.lang.Object);
     public <init>(android.view.View);
}
-keep class * extends com.stfalcon.chatkit.messages.MessageHolders$IncomingTextMessageViewHolder {
     public <init>(android.view.View, java.lang.Object);
     public <init>(android.view.View);
}
-keep class * extends com.stfalcon.chatkit.messages.MessageHolders$IncomingImageMessageViewHolder {
     public <init>(android.view.View, java.lang.Object);
     public <init>(android.view.View);
}
-keep class * extends com.stfalcon.chatkit.messages.MessageHolders$OutcomingImageMessageViewHolder {
     public <init>(android.view.View, java.lang.Object);
     public <init>(android.view.View);
}

# Twilio
-keep class com.twilio.chat.** { *; }
-keepattributes InnerClasses
#-keep interface com.twilio.chat.** { *; }
#-keep enum com.twilio.chat.** { *; }

## Keep native methods
-keepclasseswithmembernames class com.twilio.chat.** {
    native <methods>;
}

# Volley
-keep class com.android.volley.** { *;}
-dontwarn com.android.volley.**

-keepclassmembers,allowshrinking,allowobfuscation class com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher {
    void processRequest();
}
-keepclassmembers,allowshrinking,allowobfuscation class com.android.volley.CacheDispatcher {
    void processRequest();
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to set

```
android {
     compileSDKVersion 29
}
```

Comment: You should try to explain how this helps and what the problem was.

Comment: don't know why but that worked for me, would you be able to explain why Sdk 29 worked and 28 didn`t?

Comment: This works because the androidx libraries are so new that they are referencing APIs added in level 29. When proguard runs it complains about references to classes it doesn't know about since that is a sign you may be producing a bad build. When you compile a project using andoidx libraries against API level lower than 29 then proguard can't find all the references. So the choice is to help proguard resolve the references with this answer or tell proguard to be quiet with the dontwarn answer.

Comment: @satur9nine it resolve warnings but release apk crash. and crash log is **android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class TextView** any clue?

Comment: @GiruBhai suggest you ask a new question with the full stack trace. Not enough information to diagnose with just that small piece.

Answer (score 0):

Just use this:

```
-dontwarn androidx.appcompat.widget.**
```

Don't forget to remove:

```
-dontnote androidx.**
-dontwarn androidx.**
```

Answer (score 0):

update gradle plugin version

```
buildscript {
 repositories {

    google()
    jcenter()

}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}
```